# Как принять данные?

Tags: java, android, firebase

У меня есть метод звонка по нажатию кнопки

```
button_call=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_call);


button_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+79142214012"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
    }
}
```

И метод передачи данных в Firebase

```
private void validateClientInfo() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(client_edit.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите имя", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(client_number.getText().toString())){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Введите номер", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            HashMap<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
  
userMap.put("uid", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());          
            userMap.put("numberphone_client",client_number.getText().toString());
         clientRef.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).updateChildren(userMap);
            startActivity(new Intent(ClientName.this,HomeActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

Расшифровки

```
client_number=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.client_number);
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Как сделать чтобы номер передаваемый в firebase принимался в активити звонка?

Comment: О чём вопрос - вообще не понятно. Сформулируйте проблему так, чтобы она была понятна не только вам. Вы хотите по нажатию `button_call` получить из базы номер и его вызвать?

Comment: Да,чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку принимался номер и происходил вызов

Comment: `intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + client_number.getText().toString()));`?